# Replace all question mark and equal sign by slash?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way to replace all question mark, '&' , and equal sign by slash ???

currently I am only replacing php extensions by .html

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

now, if the websites url is this

```
http://www.mydomain.com/session/image-display.php?image=1&id=59
```

the user should get

```
http://www.mydomain.com/session/image-display.html/image/1/id/59
```

--edited---

I just need a example so that i could write them for other pages as well.
also how to rewrite 2 or more rewrite rules ??

Comment: You know that this is the other way around, right? You would have to replace slashes by `?`, `&` or `=`, depending on where they occur.

Comment: Yes most certainly there is a way, but it might mean that you need create your own apache module for it. Hint: It is not useful to ask "if there is a way" because most certainly there is one.

Comment: yes,but i am bit new to this , if i could get a example , i could write for the whole website isn't it ??

Comment: Well, you should start researching about that in the apache mod_rewrite manual, it has these introduction topics. Asking here on SO will most likely only give you a little fraction (and not further explained) code-chunks that will mostly only misguide you because the information needed to understand the rules is not given to you here by those quick answers. - Docs are here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Comment: docs will do i guess...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you gave, you can use this:

```
RewriteRule ^session/image-display.html/image/(.*)/id/(.*) 
/session/image-display.php?image=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

The [L] at the end is optional, it tells Apache to stop looking for other rules if this one is applied

Comment: L will, if that rule is applied and the URI is rewritten (changes), re-enter the next round of the rewrites. That flag you mean is probably [\[END\] flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) which won't enter the next round.

Comment: @hakre I didn't see any redirect rules in the OP's post so [L] will stop all further rules from being applied

Comment: Wrong. Even it stops all further rules for *the current round*, it will start all rules in the *next round* (as you changed the URI). And also wrong: If it would be a redirect, there would have been no need for this flag, as redirects exit immediately (like END does). So telling L would be find because it is not a Redirect, makes no sense (technically spoken). I hope this clarifies this a little.

Comment: @hakre There is no next round of redirects based on the OP's code so [L] in this case does the same thing as [END].  I hope this clarifies it for you, since you seem confused

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your links so that they look like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/session/image-display.html/image/1/id/59
```

Then add this in the htaccess file in your document root, before any rules that you may already have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /session/image-display\.php\?image=([^&]+)&id=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /session/image-display.html/image/%1/id/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^session/image-display\.html/image/([^/]+)/id/([^/]+) /session/image-display.php?image=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/image/([^/]+)/id/([^/]+)$ $1.php?image=$2&id=$3 [NC]
```

Comment: This, of course, only works for this exact case and won't generalise to other arguments.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 rules will internally rewrite `/session/image-display.html/n1/v1/n2/v2/n3/v3` to `/session/image-display.php?n3=v3&n2=v2&n1=v1`

**There can be any number of `/name/value` *pairs* as this rule is pretty generic.**

```
# this rule will be applied as many times as there are /name/value pairs in URI
# after /session/image-display.html
RewriteRule ^(session/image-display\.html)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(.*)$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

# this rule be applied in the last then all /name/value pairs have been converted
# into query string
RewriteRule ^(session/image-display)\.html/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```